# Form two columns using blueprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, nested-forms, blueprint-css

I have a form in my rails app that I want to show up in two columns. Since I'm using blueprint I could figure out how to do that if it were just one model, but it's a nested model I'm trying to deal with. The review_questions are a nested model.

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
  <div class="add_question_review">
    <%= f.fields_for :review_questions do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'review_question_fields', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want the fields_for to be in two columns. Is there a way to render two fields at a time? So I can just make two columns as I go?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in CSS.  CSS3 provides a nifty [Column Module](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn/), but alas it isn't very handy if your users are using older browsers.  There is a [work around](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/) that will produce a similar effect, but it takes a little more work to make it happen.

Both methods require that you return your field list inside of list tags in order for them to work, but it shouldn't be a problem.